# CMS permalink and templating system how to?

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, templating

I want to understand how to use templating system and permalinks on php websites :D !..

let me describe my self more,

1.currently i have 20 files each have its own php logic (index.php,wizard.php,search.php etc)
ALL use same class's and includes.(install.php include all the required for all class's in my project abd u require_once(install.php) in all files)

i wana remodel my website into.

```
Analyze URL requested ---> IDENTIFY requested page ---> GET TEMPLATE for THIS PAGE -->MODIFY header(meta) and footer(javascript) ---> add logic ---> display page :D.
```

can some one put me on right learning track :D !. cuz i hv coded my website fully in oop and made all its content loads dynamically from MYSQL (simple small CMS) but i have no clue how to join template and php into index without repeating my self and create different file for each page in my web ! (each file do different jobs of course like file users.php does login and registration and userprofile etc)

Hope my english wassnt too too bad and u could understand my question :D !

My current approach so far:

Mysql table : page_tbl
columns: pagename,LogicFile,templateFile,MetaTag.

index.php?pagename

will check if not already cached or not listed for chacing it will :

```
Mysql:SELECT * WHERE pagename='$_GET['page']'
```

**loginfiles** = cars.php,search.php (will be exploded with , and included)
**Template files** = will be also exploded and modified according to MetaTag.
**Metatag**: Serialized assoc array with ['name']=['value'];

Then i start buffer output , replace template with new descriptions and keywords(auto generated)
include logic files
include footer.php (which include the scripts)

am i near to correct rout or still far away ? or am did i lose my track and over killing

Comment: So you do not want a templating system? You want to design one yourself for learning how to?

Comment: well i actual dont know is there already an established templating system i can use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are unsure whether you want to write your own, or use an existing one.

- It is going to be a quite possibly very rewarding experience but a very time consuming one to write your own.
- If you have a task at hand that you need to be solved, use an existing one.

That being said there are plenty of templating systems, **smarty** being the most long-lived one. You can find a short discussion on [5 popular ones at phpbuilder](http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/5-template-engines/Jason_Gilmore04072011.php3?print_mode=1).

You also have entire Frameworks that you might want to consider. They are more than just a templating system, where database stuff, ajax helpers etc are included. **Zend**, **CakePHP**, and **Codeigniter** being popular ones. You can find [comparisons of these at phpframeworks.](http://www.phpframeworks.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to take this route:

- parse request data
- determine controller which will be used
- in controller select layout and template [layout "includes" template, it hold the contents that are common to all pages and template has the request-specific content]
- in controller also fetch the data from database [MVP way]
- assign data to array and pass it to the layout, it'll pass the data futher to the template
- in layout and template use data from that array and construct view
- pass everything to the browser

This is the way the frameworks work, and it isn't that bad. ;]

Comment: determine controller which will be used (what does that means :o ?)

Comment: For example if you use GET request, you'll check ?page=gallery&action=index or ?page=news&action=display&id=3 to urilize the file /controllers/gallery.php or /controllers/news.php. It may be also mod_rewrite reqauests, so you'll have /gallery or /news/3 respectively.

Comment: See this: http://www.elated.com/articles/mod-rewrite-tutorial-for-absolute-beginners/ .